# Qual o máximo de arquivos que posso ter em uma pasta?

Tags: diretório

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web para rodar no linux.

No meu projeto o visitante do meu site poderá enviar imagens quantas vezes ele quiser.
Minha estrutura de pastas para upload de imagens será separada por ano/mês. Parecido com a estrutura do WordPress para uploads de arquivos:

```
/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/imagem.jpg
```

**A pergunta é:**
Existe um limite de quantidade de arquivos em uma única pasta? Se por exemplo em um único mês eu tiver no meu site 1.000.000 de imagens na pasta `2014/09`? 
**Outra pergunta:**
Se houver muitos arquivos em uma pasta, o desempenho fica comprometido ao solicitar um arquivo na pasta?

Creio que depende do sistema de arquivo e as vezes fico me perguntando:
Como as grandes empresas como facebook e google lidam com quantidade de arquivos e pastas?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Existe sim um limite, mas quem impõe isso não é o sistema operacional, e sim o sistema de arquivos. Verifique qual sistema de arquivos seu servidor usa, e busque pela sua quantidade máxima de arquivos por pasta. [Nessa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/466596/520779) tem vários, mas não todos, de modo que alguma pesquisa adicional pode ser necessária. Vou transcrever a lista aqui, e complementar com alguns mais:

## [FAT32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32):

- Máximo número de arquivos: 268,173,300
- Máximo número de arquivos por pasta: 2<sup>16</sup> - 1 (65,535)
- Máximo tamanho de arquivo: 2 GiB - 1 sem [LFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_file_support), 4 GiB - 1 com

## [NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS):

- Máximo número de arquivos: 2<sup>32</sup> - 1 (4,294,967,295)
- Máximo tamanho de arquivo

  - Implementação: 2<sup>44</sup> - 2<sup>6</sup> bytes (16 TiB - 64 KiB)
  - Teórico: 2<sup>64</sup> - 2<sup>6</sup> bytes (16 EiB - 64 KiB)
- Máximo tamanho de volume

  - Implementação: 2<sup>32</sup> - 1 clusters (256 TiB - 64 KiB)
  - Teórico: 2<sup>64</sup> - 1 clusters

## [ext2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2):

- Máximo número de arquivos: 10<sup>18</sup>
- Máximo número de arquivos por pasta: ~1.3 × 10<sup>20</sup> (problemas de performance a partir de uns 10.000)
- Máximo tamanho de arquivo

  - 16 GiB (blocos de tamanho 1 KiB)
  - 256 GiB (blocos de tamanho 2 KiB)
  - 2 TiB (blocos de tamanho 4 KiB)
  - 2 TiB (blocos de tamanho 8 KiB)
- Máximo tamanho de volume

  - 4 TiB (blocos de tamanho 1 KiB)
  - 8 TiB (blocos de tamanho 2 KiB)
  - 16 TiB (blocos de tamanho 4 KiB)
  - 32 TiB (blocos de tamanho 8 KiB)

## [ext3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3):

- Máximo número de arquivos: min(tamanhoVolume / 2<sup>13</sup>, numeroDeBlocos)
- Máximo tamanho de arquivo: *mesmo que ext2*
- Máximo tamanho de volume: *mesmo que ext2*

## [ext4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4):

- Máximo número de arquivos: 2<sup>32</sup> - 1 (4,294,967,295)
- Máximo número de arquivos por pasta: ilimitado
- Máximo tamanho de arquivo: 2<sup>44</sup> - 1 bytes (16 TiB - 1)
- Máximo tamanho de volume: 2<sup>48</sup> - 1 bytes (256 TiB - 1)

## [ReiserFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReiserFS):

- Máximo número de arquivos: 2<sup>32</sup>−3 (~4 bilhões)
- Máximo tamanho de arquivo: 1 EiB (8 TiB em sistemas de 32 bits)
- Máximo tamanho de volume: 16 TiB

## [ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS):

- Máximo número de arquivos: ilimitado
- Máximo número de arquivos por pasta: 2<sup>48</sup>
- Máximo tamanho de arquivo: 16 exbibytes (2<sup>64</sup> bytes)
- Máximo tamanho de volume: 256 trilhões de yobibytes (2<sup>128</sup> bytes)

Quanto à performance, também vai depender do sistema de arquivos, mas a princípio eu diria que não há problema: se você tem um nome de arquivo completo, carregá-lo, salvá-lo etc não depende de quantos arquivos há na pasta. É na hora de **enumerá-los** que a coisa fica complicada. De acordo com [essa resposta no serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/98272/106111), o problema é mais significativo nos sistemas de arquivos mais antigos, onde não se previa um número muito grande de arquivos.

> - NTFS: Embora ele possa armazenar 4 bilhões de arquivos por pasta, ele degrada relativamente rápido - por volta de mil já se começa a perceber problemas de desempenho, vários milhares e o explorer vai parecer travar por um tempo considerável.
> - EXT3: o limite físico é 32 mil arquivos, mas a performance sofre após alguns milhares de arquivos também.
> - ReiserFS, XFS, JFS, BTRFS: esses são bons para muitos arquivos numa pasta já que são mais modernos e projetados para manipular muitos arquivos (os demais foram projetados na época em que os discos rígidos eram medidos em MB e não em GB). O desempenho é muito melhor pois eles usam busca binária para obter o arquivo que você quer (os outros usam um algoritmo mais linear).

(Esse último comentário me deixou meio em dúvida se minha afirmação de que a performance ao acessar um arquivo individual está mesmo correta. Ainda estou convicto de que seja assim mesmo, mas uma confirmação a partir de fontes confiáveis seria desejável.)

De todo modo, se puder evitar 1 milhão de arquivos na mesma pasta, evite. Sua proposta de agrupar os arquivos por ano e mês é boa, e pessoalmente não acredito que seja necessário agrupar também em dia. Mas se o custo de se fazer isso não for muito alto, por que não? Se por outro lado for demandar alterações significativas no seu projeto, sugiro esperar para lidar com o problema quando e se ele surgir.

Comment: Poderia juntar as duas respostas dos links que vc me mandou em uma única resposta e responder aqui nessa pergunta?

Comment: Acrescentaria um conhecimento enorme à comunidade SO BR!

Comment: @RowAraujo Posso sim, e vou aproveitar para dar uma pesquisada em quais sistemas de arquivos os linuxes modernos usam.

Comment: Obrigado pela atualização!

Comment: Olá! Obrigado pela informação, mas acessando o link do serverfault que você deu verifica-se que ele foi atualizado e a informação agora está mais atualizada com relação ao que você colocou, sugiro que os visitantes consultem a fonte citada sobretudo a respeito do ext3 em que o limite citado 32000 refere-se a subdiretórios e não à quantidade de arquivos. Abraço!

Comment: @agofearth Obrigado pelas informações! Resposta atualizada.